# Generating verilog for riscv-sodor

Tags: makefile, riscv, chisel

I'm working on riscv-sodor and I want to modify the Makefile to generate Verilog. How can I do this task?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

From the Sodor README (https://github.com/ucb-bar/riscv-sodor):

**How can I generate Verilog myself?**

You can generate the Verilog code by modifying the Makefile in emulator/common/Makefile.include. In the CHISEL_ARGS variable, change "--backend c" to "--backend v". This will dump a Top.v verilog file of the core and its scratchpad memory (corresponding to the Chisel module named "Top") into the location specified by "--targetDir" in CHISEL_ARGS.

Once you have the Top.v module, you will have to write your own testharness and glue code to talk to Top.v. The main difficulty here is that you need to link the riscv-fesvr to the Sodor core via the HTIF link ("host-target interface"). This allows the fesvr to load a binary into the Sodor core's scratchpad memory, bring the core out of reset, and communicate with the core while it's running to handle any syscalls, error conditions, or test successful/end conditions.

This basically involves porting emulator/*/emulator.cpp to Verilog. I recommend writing a Verilog testharness that interfaces with the existing C++ code (emulator/common/htif_emulator.cc, etc.). emulator/common/htif_main.cc shows an example stub that uses Synopsys's DirectC to interface between a Verilog test-harness and the existing C++ code.